# Problems with Python running apt-get upgrade

Tags: apt, package-management, python

When I'm trying to make apt-get upgrade I'm getting the following errors:

```
Preparing to unpack .../python-samba_2%3a4.3.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.3_amd64.deb ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 25, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/optparse.py", line 90, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gettext.py", line 49, in <module>
    import locale, copy, os, re, struct, sys
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 19, in <module>
    import functools
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/functools.py", line 72, in <module>
    root = max(roots)       # prefer __lt__ to __le__ to __gt__ to __ge__
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'compose'
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 25, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/optparse.py", line 90, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gettext.py", line 49, in <module>
    import locale, copy, os, re, struct, sys
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 19, in <module>
    import functools
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/functools.py", line 72, in <module>
    root = max(roots)       # prefer __lt__ to __le__ to __gt__ to __ge__
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'compose'
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python-samba_2%3a4.3.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 27, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/optparse.py", line 90, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gettext.py", line 49, in <module>
    import locale, copy, os, re, struct, sys
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 19, in <module>
    import functools
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/functools.py", line 72, in <module>
    root = max(roots)       # prefer __lt__ to __le__ to __gt__ to __ge__
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'compose'
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Preparing to unpack .../python3-problem-report_2.14.1-0ubuntu3.21_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-problem-report (2.14.1-0ubuntu3.21) over (2.14.1-0ubuntu3.20) ...
Preparing to unpack .../apport_2.14.1-0ubuntu3.21_all.deb ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 25, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/optparse.py", line 90, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gettext.py", line 49, in <module>
    import locale, copy, os, re, struct, sys
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 19, in <module>
    import functools
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/functools.py", line 72, in <module>
    root = max(roots)       # prefer __lt__ to __le__ to __gt__ to __ge__
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'compose'
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 25, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/optparse.py", line 90, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gettext.py", line 49, in <module>
    import locale, copy, os, re, struct, sys
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 19, in <module>
    import functools
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/functools.py", line 72, in <module>
    root = max(roots)       # prefer __lt__ to __le__ to __gt__ to __ge__
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'compose'
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/apport_2.14.1-0ubuntu3.21_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 27, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/optparse.py", line 90, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gettext.py", line 49, in <module>
    import locale, copy, os, re, struct, sys
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 19, in <module>
    import functools
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/functools.py", line 72, in <module>
    root = max(roots)       # prefer __lt__ to __le__ to __gt__ to __ge__
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'compose'
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Preparing to unpack .../libapt-pkg4.12_1.0.1ubuntu2.14_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libapt-pkg4.12:amd64 (1.0.1ubuntu2.14) over (1.0.1ubuntu2.13) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-samba_2%3a4.3.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.3_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/apport_2.14.1-0ubuntu3.21_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@shkodenko-pc:~#
```